# How to pass data from parent to child in template driven form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

My problem is with Template Driven Forms. I have two components (parent and child) and I want to pass default values for controls inside child component. In child component I have reference to the parent's form by viewProviders.

```
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
```

Code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvqbzv)

I want to know if it is possible to set default values for child controls from the parent without using ControlValueAccessor or passing values through Input().

**Parent Component:**

TS:

```
...
  model = {
    name: "Test",
    phone: 1234567890, // phone control is inside child component (nested-form)
  }
...
```

HTML:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required type="text">
  </div>
  <app-nested-form></app-nested-form>
</form>
```

**Child Component**

TS:

```
import { Component, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested-form',
  templateUrl: './nested-form.component.html',
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
})
export class NestedFormComponent {
  model: any = {
    phone: '',
  };

  constructor(@Host() controlContainer: ControlContainer) {
    console.log((controlContainer as NgForm).form); // phone control exists in form but without value
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use reactive forms for this?

Comment: I would really love to do that, but the whole project is written using Template Driven Forms... Therefore I am looking for a good solution using TDF.

Comment: I'd argue that there isn't a good solution using TDF, you'll always be building workarounds. Angular provides a tool for this kind of situation (reactive forms), so if whoever's running the project insists on using TDFs, you'll always have a suboptimal result.